# How to create/show tables when selected an option

Tags: javascript, html, css

The following is a selection element:

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title> </title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <select class = 'form-control'>
   <option>Select an Option:</option>
   <option>Electrical</option>
   <option>Mechanical</option>
   <option>Structural</option>
   <option>Others</option>
  </select>
 </body>
</html>
```

My desired result is that: when I click an option in the select tag, a table would pop-up. How can I do that?

Comment: javascript is the way to go

Comment: Have you tried to find out any thing or tried to do some javacript or any coding before posting the question here? If yes.. Please add what you have tried so far.

Comment: @HoneyBadger I would say it is inevitable that Javascript must be learned when you are doing webpages.

Comment: @HoneyBadger Just a suggestion, you can search google to find tons of articles or answers for your questions. I think we should restrict ourselves to post only those questions for which we really tried something and could not get an answer after lot of efforts. Please consider this as suggestion